# How would I go about deleting files that start with ~ through Windows Command Prompt/Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, microsoft-word, powershell

Microsoft Word creates hidden files that start with ~xxxxxx. Normally you cannot see them, but I save these files in my local Google Drive folder, which uploads the files online to my Google Drive account.

On Google Drive, whenever I go into a folder that contains .docx files, I see all sorts of garbage files that I have to manually delete, and .docx files are everywhere.

With Command Prompt, or even Powershell, how would I go about doing that. I think you can use powershell but I am no Powershell expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell is a bit overkill for this task (plus it introduces the possibility that you may accidentally have it expand `~` to your home directory; not good. `cmd.exe` won't do that.)

Just go into the command prompt, `cd` to the directory where your `~xxx` files are located, then run `del ~*`. [Wildcards](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490639.aspx).

Comment: You can add `/S` to do subdirectories.Cool. So now all I have to do is `del ~* /S` and bye-bye garbage